# How to install FASD on zsh on Mac

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, fasd

Not sure if this is the right place to post this, but I'm trying to install [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) via [this method](https://github.com/clvv/fasd/wiki/Installing-via-Package-Managers#mac-os-x) on my zsh. I tried following the directions but had no luck.

I have it installed via brew and I've added the line `plugins=(fasd)` in my `./zsrhc` file. I also have some other items installed in my `./zsrhc` and I don't know if its conflicts with those or where I am going wrong. See below for the `.zshrc` file contents.

When I follow the directions [here](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) and try to run the `make install` command, I get this output below. When I google this error, I see it has a lot to do with xcode which i don't have installed anymore.

```
❯ make install
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

when i run `eval "$(fasd --init auto)"`, nothing happens after it:

```
❯ eval "$(fasd --init auto)"
```

fasd install readout

```
❯ brew install fasd
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

You have 38 outdated formulae and 1 outdated cask installed.
You can upgrade them with brew upgrade
or list them with brew outdated.

Warning: fasd 1.0.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.0.1, run:
  brew reinstall fasd
```

.zshrc file

```
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi



export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/18.11.0/bin:$PATH"

ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"
source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
source ~/.zsh/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
source ~/.zsh/zsh-completions/zsh-completions.plugin.zsh

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh

# to make more edits, open ~/.p10k.zsh with `code ~/.p10k.zsh`
# this is all from youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVh4osULjP4


# FASD - https://github.com/clvv/fasd/wiki/Installing-via-Package-Managers
#https://github.com/clvv/fasd
plugins=(fasd)
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Installing fasd with brew

```
❯ brew install fasd
```

Add this to shell configuration, in your case `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
eval "$(fasd --init auto)"
```

Restart your terminal emulator. You should now be able to run `f` `a` `s` `d` `z` commands!

Or instead after installing with brew you can configure fasd as a ohmyzsh plugin: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/fasd/

#### Usage

Learn how fasd works by reading the on-line manual page:

```
man fasd
```

Here are also a few articles you can check for more information:

- https://rm-rf.ca/posts/2020/fasd/
- https://dewaka.com/blog/fasd-for-navigation/
- https://bytexd.com/how-to-use-fasd-in-linux-for-quick-access-to-files-directories/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like all I needed was the examples on how to use it. I had spent a couple of hours searching but nothing came up. I was probably searching for the wrong thing. Thank you!